# sbt release to Maven central fails with no public key error

Tags: scala, sbt, pgp, maven-central, sbt-plugin

I tried to release [better-files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files/blob/master/build.sbt) to Maven central and I am getting this error.
I tried this on fresh checkout on multiple different machines.

My steps:

### Step 1: Generate keys

```
> sbt    
sbt:better-files-root> pgp-cmd gen-key
Please enter the name associated with the key: Pathikrit Bhowmick
Please enter the email associated with the key: pathikritbhowmick@msn.com
Please enter the passphrase for the key: *********
Please re-enter the passphrase for the key: *********
[info] Creating a new PGP key, this could take a long time.
[info] Public key := /Users/pathikrit/.sbt/gpg/pubring.asc
[info] Secret key := /Users/pathikrit/.sbt/gpg/secring.asc
[info] Please do not share your secret key.   Your public key is free to share.
```

### Step 2: Release keys

```
sbt:better-files-root> pgp-cmd send-key pathikritbhowmick@msn.com hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
[info] Sending PublicKeyRing(PublicKey(27dfe5f26bf754dc, Pathikrit Bhowmick <pathikritbhowmick@msn.com>, RSA@2048)) to HkpServer(http://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371)
```

### Step 3: Run release command

```
sbt:better-files-root> +release
[info] Forcing Scala version to 2.11.12 on all projects.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to better-files-root (in build file:/Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/)
[info] Starting release process off commit: 7db21fb793ebb2471983f908f9c6e99dcb7d45f6
[info] Checking remote [origin] ...
[info] Updating ...
[info] Updating core...
[info] Done updating.
Release version [3.6.0] :
Next version [3.6.1-SNAPSHOT] :
[info] Setting version to '3.6.0'.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to better-files-root (in build file:/Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/)
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to better-files-root (in build file:/Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/)
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to better-files-root (in build file:/Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/)
[info] Packaging /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/core/target/scala-2.11/better-files_2.11-3.6.0-sources.jar ...
[info] Packaging /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/akka/target/scala-2.11/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/core/target/scala-2.11/api...
[info] Wrote /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/core/target/scala-2.11/better-files_2.11-3.6.0.pom
[info] Wrote /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/akka/target/scala-2.11/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0.pom
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/akka/target/scala-2.11/api...
[info] Packaging /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/akka/target/scala-2.11/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/core/target/scala-2.11/better-files_2.11-3.6.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
model contains 11 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/akka/target/scala-2.11/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
Please enter PGP passphrase (or ENTER to abort): *********
model contains 72 documentable templates
[error] Unable to find credentials for [Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager @ oss.sonatype.org].
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/core/target/scala-2.11/better-files_2.11-3.6.0-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging. model contains 11 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/akka/target/scala-2.11/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
Please enter PGP passphrase (or ENTER to abort): *********
model contains 72 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/core/target/scala-2.11/better-files_2.11-3.6.0-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published better-files-akka_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files-akka_2.11/3.6.0/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0-sources.jar.asc
[info]  published better-files-akka_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files-akka_2.11/3.6.0/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0-javadoc.jar
[info]  published better-files-akka_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files-akka_2.11/3.6.0/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0.jar.asc
[info]  published better-files-akka_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files-akka_2.11/3.6.0/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0-javadoc.jar.asc
[info]  published better-files-akka_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files-akka_2.11/3.6.0/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0.pom.asc
[info]  published better-files-akka_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files-akka_2.11/3.6.0/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0.pom
[info]  published better-files-akka_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files-akka_2.11/3.6.0/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0-sources.jar
[info]  published better-files-akka_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files-akka_2.11/3.6.0/better-files-akka_2.11-3.6.0.jar
[info]  published better-files_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files_2.11/3.6.0/better-files_2.11-3.6.0.jar.asc
[info]  published better-files_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files_2.11/3.6.0/better-files_2.11-3.6.0.pom.asc
[info]  published better-files_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files_2.11/3.6.0/better-files_2.11-3.6.0-javadoc.jar
[info]  published better-files_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files_2.11/3.6.0/better-files_2.11-3.6.0-sources.jar.asc
[info]  published better-files_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files_2.11/3.6.0/better-files_2.11-3.6.0-javadoc.jar.asc
[info]  published better-files_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files_2.11/3.6.0/better-files_2.11-3.6.0-sources.jar
[info]  published better-files_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files_2.11/3.6.0/better-files_2.11-3.6.0.jar
[info]  published better-files_2.11 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/better-files_2.11/3.6.0/better-files_2.11-3.6.0.pom
[success] Total time: 23 s, completed Jul 22, 2018 11:36:28 AM
[info] Setting version to '3.6.1-SNAPSHOT'.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to better-files-root (in build file:/Users/pathikrit/workspace/better-files/)
[info] [master e12f579] Setting version to 3.6.1-SNAPSHOT
[info]  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
[info] Nexus repository URL: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local
[info] sonatypeProfileName = com.github.pathikrit
[info] Reading staging repository profiles...
[info] Reading staging profiles...
[info] Closing staging repository [comgithubpathikrit-1045] status:open, profile:com.github.pathikrit(3ce6558c41fb47) description: Implicitly created (auto staging).
[info] Activity open started:2018-07-19T19:59:57.116Z, stopped:2018-07-19T20:00:04.197Z
[info] repositoryCreated: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, user:pathikrit, ip:38.125.162.165
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T20:01:29.188Z, stopped:2018-07-19T20:01:53.739Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (48fb4a38145efed7) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T20:17:08.278Z, stopped:2018-07-19T20:19:03.516Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (48fb4a38145efed7) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T21:23:18.003Z, stopped:2018-07-19T21:23:54.750Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (48fb4a38145efed7) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T22:00:37.521Z, stopped:2018-07-19T22:01:34.028Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (48fb4a38145efed7) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T22:12:14.160Z, stopped:2018-07-19T22:12:42.249Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (dbe44cf5bac37b7e) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T22:28:06.155Z, stopped:2018-07-19T22:28:34.071Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (800be7bf8a863023) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T22:33:24.787Z, stopped:2018-07-19T22:35:08.982Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (800be7bf8a863023) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T22:35:30.600Z, stopped:2018-07-19T22:36:01.750Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (800be7bf8a863023) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-19T23:56:30.507Z, stopped:2018-07-19T23:57:24.229Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (dbe44cf5bac37b7e) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-20T00:05:25.838Z, stopped:2018-07-20T00:06:51.588Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (dbe44cf5bac37b7e) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-20T01:18:56.952Z, stopped:2018-07-20T01:20:14.920Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (3203329e3f571131) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-20T01:31:51.669Z, stopped:2018-07-20T01:32:34.830Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (3203329e3f571131) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-20T01:36:49.254Z, stopped:2018-07-20T01:38:56.063Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (3203329e3f571131) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-20T12:52:53.504Z, stopped:2018-07-20T12:54:05.016Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (48fb4a38145efed7) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[info] Activity close started:2018-07-20T14:41:07.942Z, stopped:2018-07-20T14:44:21.132Z
[info]   Evaluate: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, rule:sources-staging
[info]   Evaluate: pom-staging
[info]     Passed: pom-staging
[info]   Evaluate: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]     Passed: no-traversal-paths-in-archive-file
[info]   Evaluate: checksum-staging
[info]     Passed: checksum-staging
[info]   Evaluate: signature-staging
[info]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (48fb4a38145efed7) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Upload your public key and try the operation again.
[info]   Evaluate: javadoc-staging
[info]     Passed: javadoc-staging
[info]   Evaluate: sources-staging
[info]     Passed: sources-staging
[info]     Failed: id:5e9e8e6f8d20a3, failureCount:1
[info] repositoryCloseFailed: id:comgithubpathikrit-1045, cause:com.sonatype.nexus.staging.StagingRulesFailedException: One or more rules have failed
[error] Failed to close the repository
[error] Activity close started:2018-07-20T14:41:07.942Z, stopped:2018-07-20T14:44:21.132Z
[error]     Failed: signature-staging, failureMessage:No public key: Key with id: (48fb4a38145efed7) was not able to be located on <a href="http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/">http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/</a>. Uploadyour public key and try the operation again.
[error] java.lang.Exception: Failed to close the repository
[error]         at xerial.sbt.Sonatype$NexusRESTService.closeStage(Sonatype.scala:762)
[error]         at xerial.sbt.Sonatype$NexusRESTService.closeAndPromote(Sonatype.scala:854)
[error]         at xerial.sbt.Sonatype$SonatypeCommand$.$anonfun$sonatypeReleaseAll$2(Sonatype.scala:279)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)   
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:151)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$div$colon$(TraversableOnce.scala:151)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]         at scala.Function$.$anonfun$chain$1(Function.scala:24)
[error]         at sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin$autoImport$ReleaseKeys$.$anonfun$releaseCommand$2(ReleasePlugin.scala:199)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:134)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:130)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:154)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:137)
[error]         at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:242)
[error]         at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:248)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:137)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:137)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:130)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:108)
[error]         at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:102)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:58)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:43)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]         at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:113)
[error]         at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:76)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Failed to close the repository
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
sbt:better-files-root>
```

I filed an issue with sbt-release but I have not got any response to it either: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release/issues/233

Answer (score 1):

In order to access instantly the public key, there is the need to add it to the server that the CI will be using.

It seems that your build is trying to fetch a key from this server `http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/` and you publish the key on this server 
`hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net` according to step two described above.
At some point, it will be available in different servers but the synchronization is not instantaneous.

To fix that run the step two now using the Ubuntu server:

This will send your PGP key to the Ubuntu keyserver. To do this, first, run

```scala
sbt:better-files-root> pgp-cmd send-key pathikritbhowmick@msn.com hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

or

```sh
gpg --send-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com keyid; replace keyid with your key ID.
```

For the previous server as well, without using sbt:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys keyid
```